# std::result_of for built-in operators

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

What is the proper syntax for determining result of something like `-int()` or `double()*double()` via `result_of`?

This fails

```
std::result_of<operator-(int)>::type
std::result_of<operator*(double,double)>::type
```

Comment: You may use `decltype` instead.

Comment: @b4hand `typename` is only necessary if the arguments passed to the template are dependent on template parameters. `int` and `double` are not dependent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::result_of` is really not the approach to take here. `decltype` does exactly what you want, and can be used as `decltype(-int())`, `decltype(double()*double())` etc. If you don't know if the type is default-constructible, you can also use `std::declval`: `decltype(-std::declval<int>())`.

The reason any syntax involving `operator-` won't work is because the `operator-` syntax only works for custom overloaded operators. Built-in operators don't have any backing function that can be referred to.

Answer (score 3):

`decltype` is definitely the way to go here, but if you must use `result_of`, it can be done by using the [function objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) defined in `<functional>`

For instance, to get the resulting type of `double * double`, use

```
std::result_of<std::multiplies<double>(double, double)>::type
```

Similarly, unary negation would be

```
std::result_of<std::negate<int>(int)>::type
```

With C++14, you can even query the resulting type of a mathematical operation on two different types

```
std::result_of<std::plus<>(double, int)>::type
```

Of course, this same technique can be used for user defined types as well

```
struct foo{};
struct bar{};
bar operator/(foo, foo) { return bar{}; }

std::result_of<std::divides<>(foo, foo)>::type
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b8894b5fe8ba1a9)